# Pandas groupby and pivot table plotting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

[image]

I have a data set as such and I want to plot a bar graph showing popluation differences between `rural and urban` states of all states mentioned .

I tried using groupby -

```
Literacy_States=Rural_Urban[['Name','TRU','M_LIT','F_LIT']]


Literacy_States=Literacy_States.groupby(['Name','TRU'])['M_LIT','F_LIT'].count().unstack('TRU').plot.bar()
```

But the output I get is as -
[image]

**Please help me out with this code . What I expect is something like-**

[image]

With `male female`  replaced with `Rural Urban`

Link to the data set-
https://github.com/Irene-123/Data-sets/blob/main/state_dist_sc.xls

Comment: Post your dataframe sample as text rather than an image.

Comment: I have added a link to that data set @Vishnudev

Comment: I checked the dataset shared, are you sure it includes the column having values like Private, Self-emp-inc etc the one you are using as x-axis on expected graph?

Comment: On x-axis , ```Name``` is used which is a column for ```states``` @SAL

Comment: But that column includes cities too.

Comment: I have cleared those using ```onlyStates=df_State[df_State['TRU']=='Total']
onlyStates.head()```

Comment: Check the picture of data set I mentioned above  which only includes ```states```

Comment: Is this the solution ? Could you put it into an answer please @Hasnat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unwanted total row from the data and get the rows which are states

```
Literacy_States = Literacy_States[(Literacy_States.TRU != 'Total') & (Literacy_States.Level == 'State')].copy()
```

Create a column for the total population

```
Literacy_States['population'] = Literacy_States[['M_LIT', 'F_LIT']].sum(axis=1)
```

Plot the population in Urban and Rural based on Name column

```
Literacy_States.groupby(['Name', 'TRU'])['population'].sum().unstack(1).plot.bar(rot=45)
```

[image]